# Android Studio improper content_main xml on fresh install?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I just got android studio and I have some questions as my screen is different from the tutorial on lynda.com . The design tab for my content_main.xml file is just a blue square[image: design]
However, the tutorial has this screen instead.
[image]. This seems to fix itself when I closed the project and reopened it. However, instead of Hello World the tutorial has in the middle of the screen, I have android...Coordinator Layout as seen below. What have I done wrong as I literally just downloaded Android Studio...
[image]

Comment: The tutorial is using an older version of android studio, the look changed a bit thats all

Comment: can you show me your dependcies in build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

make sure your styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: ? It still says android...Coordinator Layout

Answer (score 0):

Make sure style is (parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">)